Is the detector separate from a system already in an eigenstate of the measurement operator?
The measurement process always alters the quantum system (collapse of the wave function; collapse of superposition to one definite state), except for when the system is already in an eigenstate of the measured observable. In these cases, the measurement will not alter the system.
My question is: just as the measurement device, or detector, is separate from the quantum systems they alter/collapse, is it also separate from a system already in an eigenstate of the measurement operator?

I just made a couple revisions for grammar.

I went on to edit the title after this comment. It is proper now. I look forward to reading the input this gets.

Can you clarify (or provide an intuition for) what you mean by "separate"? For instance, you could say that the system and apparatus are "separate" in a trivial sense$-$they can be thought of as two different quantum systems. But perhaps this is not quite what you're getting at.

@Jonomyster Yes, and thank you for engaging. By 'separate', I mean: independent of the system it is detecting/measuring. The eigenstate case I cited is the only time where the detector doesn't alter the system. In all other measurement cases, the detectors dramatically alter the state of the system. The way the detector is considered separate from the quantum systems they alter, is it considered separate from the systems they don't alter (in the eigenstate cases)?

I'm inclined to say that "yes, they are separate" in both cases. Maybe I can illustrate this with an example. Consider a particle with spin-$1/2$, and consider a detector that measures that spin along some direction. Let's define the $z$-axis to be the orientation of that detector. We can further define the quantum states $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$ to be the spin eigenstates that the particle is found in, after the measurement has occurred. (Cont.)

These states are "independent" of the detector in the sense that they are just arbitrary base states we can express the particle's spin in. But of course they are "special" in that they are the ones picked out by measurement. Note that any particle's spin can be expressed in terms of these states: $a|\uparrow\rangle+ b|\downarrow \rangle$.
Then, I guess that in the measurement of both $|\uparrow\rangle$ and the superposition $a|\uparrow\rangle+ b|\downarrow \rangle$, the particle is "separate" from the detector.
Is that the general idea behind your question?

@Jonomyster Thank you again. Yeah, the general idea behind my question is that I'm curious how the measurement problem applies in the case of the system already being in an eigenstate of the measurement operator. Seeing as the eigenstate of measurement operator case is the only case where the quantum system being measured isn't altered upon measurement, I'm curious if people (namely physicists) view the measurement problem in the case of the eigenstate measurement operator the same way they do in all the cases where measurement alters the systems.

Within the Copenhagen interpretation, the detector and system are always separate and interact in a 'special manner' when compared to other sorts of interactions that can be deterministically described in terms of the Schrodinger equation (e.g. an external electric field acting in an atom). In the case of the system being in an eigenstate of the observable, the wavefunction collapses all the same by the action of observing, except in this case, it can only collapse in itself.
This strange and not properly understood relationship between system and observable is uncomfortable for many, and there have been several attempts to construct an interpretation of quantum mechanics in
which the wavefunction maintains its continuity even upon measurement. An example would be Hugh Everett's many-worlds interpretation.
